# Pasting blank picture(Bitmap) only for 1 slide remaining working as expected while pasting data from Excel to power point using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am trying to copy paste data from excel to powerpoint slide.

Data is copied in bitmap format and pasted to slides. This is a repeated process and is put in a loop.

When i debug and do everything works fine. But when I perform a complete run in any one of the slide blank image gets pasted.This slide varies in each run.

During the run the image will have a red 'x' mark and a message saying 'This image cannot be displayed now'. But once the run is completed and if you open the ppt, that slide will have a blank picture.

```
'Copy-Paste the data to PPT Slide
         Workbooks("Statistics").Worksheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.CopyPicture_Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap                      

                    Set PPSlide = PPFile.Slides(PPFile.Slides.Count)
                    PPSlide.Select
                    PPSlide.Shapes.Paste
                    Set myshape = PPSlide.Shapes(PPSlide.Shapes.Count)


                    Application.CutCopyMode = False

                    'Set position
                    myshape.Left = 40
                    myshape.Top = 90
                    myshape.Width = 700
```

Comment: Has "Sheet3" been activated at all, to ensure that the range is loaded into the VRAM or graphics buffer?

Comment: Hi Chronocidal,.. Thanks for you response..Not activated..but wherever is required I'm taking as worksheet("sheet3")